# Changing colour change in uidraw

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, drawing

Hi is there any way i can change the color programatically with a button?

>

```
-(void)drawToBuffer {

//                  Red  Gr   Blu  Alpha
CGFloat color[4] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};


if (self.previousPoint != nil) {
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(offScreenBuffer, color[0], color[1], color[2], color[3]);

    CGContextBeginPath(offScreenBuffer);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(offScreenBuffer, 5.0);
    CGContextSetLineCap(offScreenBuffer, kCGLineCapRound);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(offScreenBuffer, previousPoint.location.x, previousPoint.location.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(offScreenBuffer, point.location.x, point.location.y);

    CGContextDrawPath(offScreenBuffer, kCGPathStroke);
}
```

}

this belongs to a uidraw view and im hoping to create a eraser function for the UiDraw in my app

Comment: its now black i want to change it to white so it would act like a eraser

Answer (score 1):

Just change color value to white...i.e., change color[4]={1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0} which is white....

Color takes r,g,b,a as color components range from 0.0 to 1.0 in float value or 1 to 255 in int value. And component a stands for transparency.

Comment: i know that what i need is to change the color using a button within the app while its running

Comment: Pass the required color as parameter to the above function for the event of button

Comment: Please don't be rude to people asking questions here. I've edited out your inappropriate comment from your answer, but don't do this again.